# "Totally agree" and "completely agree"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adverbs

What is the difference between *totally agree* and *completely agree*? In other words, what is the difference in meaning between *totally* and *completely* in such combinations in conversations?

Comment: Synonymous to me. Sometimes one simply looks at the surrounding context and decides which sounds or reads best, or best fits the style of the piece.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They mean the same thing, along with "fully agree" or "entirely agree".  Either means agreement to the maximum possible and without any element of disagreement. "Totally" has picked up a connotation of sounding a bit ditzy but that seems to be on the decline.  Otherwise, use whichever sounds better in context.